# UISearchBar AutoLayout ios7 bug?

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I'm using AutoLayout and have a UISearchBar, UITableView ad a UIView. Initially the layout is correct and positioned according to my AutoLayout rules.

[image]

When the UISearchBar has focus it expands abruptly in height covering my top UIView.

[image]

No matter how I layout my autolayout constraints this happens.

If I don't set

```
self.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

and set a frame instead then it behaves as normal.

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0f, 45.0f)];
```

But i'm reliant upon AutoLayout in this app for iOS7. Is this a genuine bug? Or most probably i've missed something!

Comment: You can add height constraints to your UISearchBar view.

Comment: Yes I have tried that as an additional constraint, makes zero difference.

Comment: Did you add top, leading, trailing and height constraints to your UISearchBar view?

Comment: Hello @JMWhittaker, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Try this in viewDidLoad

```c
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: This didn't help with my layout but I get your thinking on this.